# Why is my LINQ query not recognizing members of a generic list?

Tags: c#, linq, class, generics, generic-list

I am trying to query (via LINQ) a generic list, and it is "acting" as if some of the fields I'm "whereing on" do not exist.

Here is the code:

```
private decimal GetPriceForMember_Code_Desc_Unit_Week(string member, string itemcode, string desc, string unit, int weeknum)
{
    Decimal price = 0.00M;
    if (unit == CRAFTWORKS_SC)
    {
        price = craftworksWeek1PVDSubsetList.Select(x => x.Price)
            .Where(x => x.ShortName.Equals(member))
            .Where(x => x.Description.Equals(desc))
            .Where(x => x.WeekNum.Equals(weeknum))
            .Where(x => x.ItemCode.Equals(itemcode));
    }
    //else if (unit == CHOPHOUSE) TODO: Finish
    return price;
}
```

It fails with, "*'string' does not contain a definition for 'ShortName' and no extension method 'ShortName' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

There's apparently something wrong with my LINQ syntax, but I don't know what. The generic list in the code is defined and declared like so:

```
public class PriceVarianceSubsetData
{
    public String ShortName { get; set; }
    public String ItemCode { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; } //<= need this, too?
    public String Price { get; set; }
    public int WeekNum { get; set; }
}
. . .
List<PriceVarianceSubsetData> craftworksWeek1PVDSubsetList = null;
```

Why does it have no qualms about "Price" yet complains about "ShortName"? They are both members of the class "PriceVarianceSubsetData"

Comment: umm you use .Select() to only select the Price property i.e. that is the only property available. perhaps you should move the .Select to the end of the query instead

Comment: Move `Select` to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq queries are applied to list in order.
In your case the order is

1. From list of `PriceVarianceSubsetData` take `Prises`
2. Filter list of `Prices` by `ShortName`
   ...

As a result you get an error.

The correct way is to filter the initial list first and then select the value you need.

```
craftworksWeek1PVDSubsetList.Where(...).Select();
```

Also in this case as a result you get list of all prices (`IEnumerable<string>`), that satisfy your conditons. You can take only one value by using `Single()` method. The method choise depends on desired behavior. You should select from Single/First/SingleOrDefault/FirstOrDefault methods.

And `Price` is string and you want double. You should parse the string value into double.

The code will be

```
string stringPrice = craftworksWeek1PVDSubsetList
        .Where(x => x.ShortName.Equals(member))
        .Where(x => x.Description.Equals(desc))
        .Where(x => x.WeekNum.Equals(weeknum))
        .Where(x => x.ItemCode.Equals(itemcode))
        .Select(x => x.Price)
        .Single();
price = Double.Parse(stringPrice);
```

Comment: Is Single() to be preferred over FirstOrDefault()? If so, why? There are times where there is no match...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon `.Single()` means your program will throw an exception when more than one item fits all the filter. Think twice about using it, and be sure its the only possibility.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you face is that once the `Select` method runs, you are iterating over strings, just move the select to the end, and it will work

You are also creating many unnecessary iterators, every Linq method returns an iterator

I would try

```
price = craftworksWeek1PVDSubsetList
        .Where(x => x.ShortName.Equals(member) &&
                    x.Description.Equals(desc) &&
                    x.WeekNum.Equals(weeknum) &&
                    x.ItemCode.Equals(itemcode))
         .Select(x => x.Price);
```